# Aggregate function in nested case statement requiring potentially messy group by

Tags: oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

Pseudocode to describe what I'm looking at:

```
SELECT
  COLUMN_A
, COLUMN_B
, CASE WHEN (OUTER_CONDITION_A = TRUE) THEN
       CASE WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_1 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 1'
            WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_2 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 2'
            WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_3 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 3'
       ELSE 'Other Choice' END
  ELSE CASE WHEN (OUTER_CONDITION_B = TRUE) THEN
       CASE WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_4 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 4'
            WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_5 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 5'
            WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_6 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 6'
       ELSE TO_CHAR(MAX(DATE)) END
  END AS 'COLUMN_C'
, COLUMN_D
FROM TABLE_A
```

Oracle SQL Developer is telling me that I need to add a GROUP BY clause:

GROUP BY
  COLUMN_A
, COLUMN_B
, COLUMN_D

When I try to run this, I get an ORA-00979 (not a GROUP BY expression) error. I'm stumped here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an aggregate function `MAX(DATE)` in the case statement along with other columns without any group by clause.

Assuming, you want to get the overall max date in each row, you can use analytic `MAX(DATE) OVER ()`:

```
SELECT
  COLUMN_A
, COLUMN_B
, CASE WHEN (OUTER_CONDITION_A = TRUE) THEN
       CASE WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_1 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 1'
            WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_2 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 2'
            WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_3 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 3'
       ELSE 'Other Choice' END
  ELSE CASE WHEN (OUTER_CONDITION_B = TRUE) THEN
       CASE WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_4 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 4'
            WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_5 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 5'
            WHEN (INNER_CONDITION_6 = TRUE) THEN 'Choice 6'
       ELSE TO_CHAR(MAX(DATE) OVER ()) END
  END AS 'COLUMN_C'
, COLUMN_D
FROM TABLE_A
```

Comment: To clarify the answer: Using an aggregate function without any `GROUP BY` clause is OK. The problem is that the OP is also selecting other things. `MAX()` without `GROUP BY` means group all rows into one big group, and the output should be just one row. But the other expressions in `SELECT ` are one value for each row of input. **That** is what can't be done: if the query is to return one row for each row of input, then it can't ALSO have aggregate functions. This is exactly where analytic functions should be used instead, exactly as GurV shows in the Answer.